# Angular 2: Resetting form ignores initial value

Tags: forms, angular

I have an Angular 2 app where I set default values for certain inputs like this:

```
this._stdSearchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    count: [{value: 50, disabled: false}, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(3), Validators.pattern("^[0-9]+$")])]
});
```

I have inplemented a "reset" feature like this:

```
(click)="resetStdSearchForm()"
```

and that just runs:

```
this._stdSearchForm.reset();
```

That resets the form, but ignores the initial value defined in the FormBuilder group.

Is this behaviour intended?

Can I programatically set the value of "count" after resetting the form? I tried doing this:

```
this._stdSearchForm.value.count = 50;
```

but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
this._stdSearchForm.setValue({ count: 50});
```

or you can do the same by:

```
this._stdSearchForm.reset({ count: 50});
```

The `reset` method resets the **[FormGroup](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#reset-anchor)**. This means by default:

- The group and all descendants are marked pristine
- The group and all descendants are marked untouched
- The value of all descendants will be null or null maps